# How if works there?

Tags: swift, if-statement, swift3

```
 func sortFunc (array: [Int], closure: (Int?, Int) -> Bool) -> Int {
     var tempVar: Int? = nil
      for value in array {
           if closure (tempVar, value) {
              tempVar = value
           }
        }

    return tempVar!
 }
```

In this code I can't understand this:

```
    if closure (tempVar, value) {
   tempVar = value
}
```

Can you explain what closure(tempVar, value) means?
I tried to find info in documentation, but there is nothing, that can help me.

Comment: Please read the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapter in the "The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down. Looking at the method signature, you can see the definition of `closure`:

```
func sortFunc (array: [Int], closure: (Int?, Int) -> Bool) -> Int
```

What this means is that there is a parameter named `closure` for the function `sortFunc` which must have two arguments, an `Int?` and `Int`, that returns a `Bool`ean value.

So what does that even mean?

That means we are passing a **function** to `sortFunc` as a parameter. An example of this would be something like this:

```
func myFunction(_ temporaryValue: Int?, value: Int) {
    // return a boolean value
    return temporaryValue != nil
}
```

When you call `if closure(tempVar, value)` it evaluates the function passed provided with the arguments of `tempVar` and `value` and returns a boolean (true/false) based on the results of that function.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

`closure` is a block of code that takes two parameters, one `Int?` and one `Int`, and returns a `Bool`.

It can be called like a function and will return a value.

When you do this `if closure(tempVar, value)`, you are calling that block of code with those two parameters, so it will return a boolean value.

Comment: Thank you for help!